# C# Reference collection object dynamically?

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, llblgen

So I need to access a class property's value dynamically at runtime but I can't figure out how to do this...any suggestions? Thanks!

```
//Works
int Order = OrdersEntity.ord_num;

//I would love for this to work.. it obviously does not.
string field_name = "ord_num";
int Order = OrdersEntity.(field_name);
```

OK so here is what I have so far with reflection, which balks unless the collection item it is looping through is a string:

```
void RefreshGrid(EntityCollection<UOffOrdersStgEcommerceEntity> collection)
        {
            List<string> col_list = new List<string>();

            foreach (UOffOrdersStgEcommerceEntity rec in collection)
            {
                foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> field in UOffOrdersStgEcommerceEntity.FieldsCustomProperties)
                {

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)rec.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(rec, null)))
                        {
                            if (!col_list.Contains<string>((string)rec.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(rec, null))) 
                                col_list.Add((string)rec.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(rec,null));
                        }

                }

                foreach (string ColName in col_list)
                {
                    grdOrders.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
                    {
                        Header = ColName,
                        Binding = new Binding(ColName)
                    });
                }               
            }

            grdOrders.ItemsSource = collection;
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this, you have to use reflection:

```
int result = (int)OrdersEntity.GetType()
                              .GetProperty("ord_num")
                              .GetValue(OrdersEntity, null);
```

Comment: so I basically have a collection of properties, which may be strings, decimals, dates, etc & I basically want to dynamically add grid columns in a WPF app if the values are not null.  Here's what I have so far, which works if all of the collection objects are strings, but they are not.  The collection object is an llblgen collection btw.. code on my next reply.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be exactly what you want to do, but try changing

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)rec.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(rec, null)))
{
    if (!col_list.Contains<string((string)rec.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(rec, null))) 
    col_list.Add((string)rec.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(rec,null));
}
```

to (with some refactoring)

```
string columnValue = rec.GetType().GetProperty(field.Key).GetValue(rec, null).ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnValue))
{
    if (!col_list.Contains(columnValue)) 
        col_list.Add(columnValue);
}
```

`GetValue()` returns an `Object`, so `ToString()` is the only way to reliably get a string in this case.